# Gradle script which invokes java program

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I wrote a simple java program in Eclipse which parses a xml file and I need to write  Gradle script which receives the path to the xml file as a property and invokes the Java program. Could you guys help me with the script? I`m new to java and this is my first time working with gradle.

Comment: does my answer solve the problem? If yes, please accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a task of type `JavaExec`. See [here](https://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html) for docs and [here](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-run-java-application.html) for a nice example.